# USCI UART on MSP430G2553

Tags: uart, msp430, hyperterminal

I am trying to learn the UART communications on MSP430G2553 and beginner. Please answer the following questions of me

1. Can UART communication be done through the default USB connection to emulator or is it necessary to use RS232 to USB converter ? Several blogs suggested USB emulator connection is sufficient for UART. If yes, please explain how USB emulator connection works for UART.
2. Assuming USB emulator connection works, I tried using hyperterminal for windows 7. I can see MSP430 assigned COM13 port in device manager but however I am not able to establish connection in hyperterminal. I tried using Putty but I wasnt able to open after giving serial port settings.

Please suggest answers or suitable links to overcome this problem.

Comment: Your LaunchPad's User's Guide tells you this is possible. The problem is that you're doing something wrong, but you have not told us what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

1. As for the Launchpad: If you are connecting the Launchpad to your PC, a COM port should "appear" as well, and the UART of the msp430g2553 is mapped onto this device. As far as I know, it is limited to a baudrate of 9600. No additional device is required
2. I assume that the msp430g2553 is programmed with an application which really handles the UART (initialized to 9600, 8N1), and is really reading characters from the UART, and writing something back. Then you should be able to access it using Hyperterminal (same settings there: 9600, 8N1).

Anyway I have experienced some problems using this way (on Linux; sometimes the serial device did not appear, and sometimes it did not work proberly after flashing the MCU). Because of the 9600 baud limitation, it's not much fun either. Therefore I am using a separate MAX3232, and a RS232-USB-Converter. This works without problems, and it works with a baudrate of 115k.

*Update*

- As for UART initialization, see "15.3.1 USCI Initialization and Reset" in the user's guide.
- As CL pointed out in a comment you need an appropriate clock for the UART (you can use the SMCLK for the UART, and the DCOCLK to feed the SMCLK. In that case the DCO  should be configured with one of the calibrated settings).

Comment: The application UART supports any baud rate, but the correct rate must be set at both ends, and the device must use an accurate enough clock.